# git ignore everything except a file, a folder, and an extension within that folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I need to create a `.gitignore` file that follows these rules:

1. Ignore everything in root
2. Except for a single file `fil.py`
3. Except for a single folder `fol/`
4. But do ignore files with the extension `.pyc` within `/fol`

I've tried several combinations, but I can't get it to work. Here's what I've tested:

1-

```
# ignore everything in root
*
# except for this file
!fil.py
# except for this folder
!/fol
# But do ignore these files
/fol/*.pyc
```

This will track changes made to files within the `fol/` folder, but will ignore *all* new files added to it.

2-

```
# ignore everything in root
*/
# except for this file
!fil.py
# except for this folder
!/fol
# But do ignore these files
/fol/*.pyc
```

This correctly tracks both old and new files within `fol/`, while ignoring `*.pyc` files; but will also track files in the root folder.

3-

```
# ignore everything in root
/*
# except for this file
!fil.py
# except for this folder
!/fol
# But do ignore these files
/fol/*.pyc
```

This correctly tracks both old and new files within `fol/`, and ignores files in the root folder. But it will also track all `*.pyc` files in the `fol/` folder.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think I found the solution. The issue is with the lats line in `.gitignore`, not with the first. Using `.pyc` in combination with the 3- option seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following .gitignore, I believe this is working as you are hoping for.

```
/*
!fil.py
!/fol
*.pyc
```

[image: working example]